# Execute Highlighted Code in Jupyter notebook Cell?

Tags: python, rstudio, jupyter-notebook, spyder

Is it possible to execute ONLY the highlighted code in a Jupyter notebook cell? This is possible in Spyder and RStudio.

I find this to be quite useful for trouble-shooting code as you write.

If a cell contains:

```
a=13
b=17
c=42
a=a*c
```

I'd like to be able to highlight and run only the desired lines (e.g. variable assignmemnts), but not the final line.

I use this frequently in Spyder and RStudio, would love to do in Jupyter as well. I find I am constantly splitting and re-combining cells in order to troubleshoot a single line of code, where for example, I've indexed into something incorrectly. Highlighting and printing the variable allows me to see what I've actually assigned it to be and is throwing an error, vs. what I had intended.

Comment: You can split cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems now it is available in python notebook as well. 
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/2191

If I open a python notebook in Kaggle (www.kaggle.com) and select a text, it lets me run only the highlighted part.

Comment: Awesome! Have you got this to work? I think I'd need to update my Jupyter version.

Comment: This does not work

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing in Jupyter as 'highligh and run'. At least I am not aware of it.

Run the cell after commenting the other lines out using <kbd>CTRL + /</kbd>, split cells and execute only the chosen ones or use a debugger (e.g. [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb), it works in Jupyter) to change variables values on the fly (while debugging).

Comment: Ok -so the highlight-and-run functionality in Spyder and RStudio is indeed not present in Jupyter notebooks? If so, add to your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.